# ionic 4 - build android - Could not find an installed version of Gradle even though it is installed

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm developing an app in Ionic 4, ubuntu 18 is my OS.
now I want to publish the app on android

when I type:
sudo ionic cordova build android --prod --release

I get the following error:

Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java"
studio
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,

but I did install gradle:

myApp git:(master) ✗ gradle -v

---

### Gradle 5.2.1

Build time:   2019-02-08 19:00:10 UTC
Revision:     f02764e074c32ee8851a4e1877dd1fea8ffb7183

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.3
Kotlin:       1.3.20
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_201 (Oracle Corporation 25.201-b09)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-45-generic amd64

also inside my ~/.zshrc file has:

```
export ZSH="/home/itamar/.oh-my-zsh"
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java"
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-5.2/bin
```

Comment: Press win Key+R type cmd then enter > in command terminal type `gradle -v` what is the output of that command?

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-01-02 18:57:47 UTC
Revision:     d09c2e354576ac41078c322815cc6db2b66d976e

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.0
Kotlin:       1.3.11
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_201 (Oracle Corporation 25.201-b09)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-45-generic amd64

Comment: im using ubuntu 18

Comment: Run `sudo apt install gradle`

Comment: gradle 5.2 is installed after I updated.. still same error

Answer (score 3):

On cordova@7.0.0 and above and SDK Tools 26.x.x you have to install gradle by your own or if gradle installed you have to make sure it is available from command line;

in my case I use windows so I have install gradle manually and extract the zip file in C drive and set the path `C:\gradle-6.0\bin`

[image: set gradle path]

check if gradle working

[image]

for Unix-based systems

```
$ sdk install gradle 6.0.1
```

for macOS you homebrew package manager

```
$ brew install gradle
```

the issue discussed [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11591) at github .

Answer (score 2):

### Solution #1

The first thing I would try is to run the command without `sudo` so just run `ionic cordova build android --prod --release`

If that doesn't work try solution #2

---

### Solution #2

What you want to do is download the gradle bundle from their [website](https://gradle.org/next-steps/?version=5.2.1&format=bin). Once you have downloaded the Gradle binaries you want to do the following:

1. Navigate to your SDK path i.e. `cd $HOME/Android/Sdk/tools`
2. Create a new folder called `gradle`
3. Navigate into the directory `cd ./gradle`
4. Extract the binaries you downloaded earlier to the folder
5. Run the command again `ionic cordova build android --prod --release`

Comment: thank you for trying to help first of all. first solution - access denied. second solution - tried and did not work also. same error

Comment: It sounds like you need to sort out permissions first. Try `cordova build android --verbose` and read the logs, there might be some files you need to grant executable access for your user to: `chmod +x ~/some-file`. You should not need to use `sudo` at all.

Comment: I guess you're correct. I did sudo -s and typed: cordova build android --verbose without sudo, and everything worked. however, I did not succeed to do it from my username (which is admin priviledges). chmod -x did not work for me. by the way why did sudo causing this error?